# An object of array must contain specific members/names

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

How can i validate an object of arrays that's passed as a parameter to my jQuery plugin to make sure it contains specific members/names?

For example, I want to validate if this object below has 'name', 'ID' & 'Location', all three members, which in this case should be true.

```
var arr = [{
    name: 'Johny',
    ID: 1,
    Location: 'USA'
}, {
    name: 'Mike',
    ID: 4,
    Location: 'CAN'
}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Johny

Comment: Would you accept extra properties?

Comment: no, should always be these 3 properties.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: @MihaiP. Well, I had no idea how to achieve this as I'm still learning JS/jQuery, after searching around & not getting a solution, I thought of asking the experts. I don't understand the down-vote.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic number 3 "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." you have done nothing to try to solve this on your own.

Comment: @MihaiP. I didn't know where to even start with this, Just needed someone to guide to the right direction. I was way off with this, I was trying to create a duplicate object and then using .is() to compare the both. There isn't anything helpful on the web regarding this.

Comment: Next time show that you tried, easy as that. You tried doing it like this (with .is()) and it did not work. brianvaughn told you the exact same thing in his first sentence. Btw, your accepted answer does not do what you want, you can pass other params and it will pass.

Comment: @MihaiP. Point taken. and yes, I realized that later, I used Object.keys as suggested by dsfq. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to test that every object in array conforms necessary keys rules:

```
var valid = arr.every(function(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return keys.length === 3 && 'name' in obj && 'ID' in obj && 'Location' in obj; 
});
```

Comment: I like this answer as well, +1 for object.keys. Its very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You should really make an effort (and show what you've tried and why it didn't work).

There are many ways to do what you're asking. Here is one:

```
arr.forEach(function(object) {
  if (!object.name || !object.ID || !object.Location) {
    throw Error("Missing properties");
  }
});
```

You could check each property individually and throw an error that said what property (or properties) was missing if that's desired.

Comment: Thanks @brianvaughn, I didn't know where to even start with this, Just needed someone to guide to the right direction. I was way off with this, I was trying to create a duplicate object and then using .is() to compare the both. This works great, thanks a lot for your time. I'll mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check each property exists by using `Object.hasOwnProperty()` like so:

```
function isValid(arr){
    // If arr is an array
    if( arr && arr.constructor === Array){
        // For each item
        for(var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++){
            var item = arr[i];
            if(   !typeof item !== 'object'
               || !item.hasOwnProperty('name')
               || !item.hasOwnProperty('ID')
               || !item.hasOwnProperty('Location')
               // This is to check if it has *exactly* those 3 properties and no more
               || Object.keys(arr).length != 3){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! good to know about Object.hasOwnProperty(). +1